How to extract chirps data with gee?
When Im trying to extract chirps data with GEE, this happened to my code 
Does anyone know about "filterdate is not a function" thing? is it caused by CHIRPS website error? or perhaps my code was wrong?

Please don't post screenshots of code - whenever possible please copy-paste the text of the code into your question so we can easily copy-paste it to run it.

Its .filterDate, not .filterdate:
var ic2 = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
 .filterDate(
  "2023-01-01","2024-01-01"
  )
  
  print(ic2)

